# Как настроить работу с FTP в VS Code?

Tags: ftp, visual-studio-code, sftp

Для работы над проектом дали адрес сервера, логин и пароль. У меня в VS Code установлено расширение `ftp-sync`, все данные введены. Но при сохранении файлов, изменения не отображаются в браузере.
В чем может быть проблема? Может неверно настроен `ftp-sync.json`?

Плюс не получается настроить расширения `ftp-simple` и `SFTP`. По инструкции, например, к `SFTP`: `Ctrl+Shift+P on Windows/Linux or Cmd+Shift+P on Mac open command palette, run SFTP: config command.`
Но когда ввожу `SFTP: config`, выводится ошибка `command 'sftp.config' not found`

При том, что такие же действия с расширением `ftp-sync` привели к созданию json файла, куда можно было ввести свои конфигурации.

Сори, коряво объясняю, но, если кто понял, мб знает, в чем трабл?

Answer (score 4):

для плагина **sftp** используйте такой *sftp.json* :

```
{
    "name": "name.ru",
    "host": "99.99.99.222", //ip сервера
    "protocol": "sftp",
    "port": 22, 
    "username": "username",
    "password": "pass",
    "remotePath": "/var/www/web/sitename", // папка которая будет открываться при подключении
    "downloadOnOpen": true,
    "uploadOnSave": true,

    "watcher": { 
        "files": "**/*",
        "autoUpload": true,
        "autoDelete": true

       }
}
```

Comment: хорошо, спасибо. только если у меня автоматически не создается sftp.json, мне его просто вручную создать? плюс в описании расширения указано, что справа на вертикальной панели VS Code должна появиться иконка этого расширения, а она у меня не появляется и никакие конфиги расширения не находятся

Comment: в vs code эти расширения так устроены, что  если у вас открыта локальная директория то он работает с вашей локальной папкой .vscode, (то есть плагин надо ставить локально) а судя по вашему вопросу сейчас у вас открываются настройки для вашего удаленного сайта, где этот плагин не установлен.

Comment: иконка должна быть в любом случае

Comment: раз иконка должна быть в любом случае, в чем может быть у меня проблема? вроде делаю все пошагово, как пишут в интернетах и говорят во всяких видео. но получается по-другому

Comment: проблема только одна значит он у вас не установлен в том окружении откуда запущен vs code, вот пример установленного плагина http://skrinshoter.ru/s/120719/oDCQNvt8?a

Comment: в том то и дело, что он установлен(

Comment: не отчаивайтесь еще масса вариантов, переустановить vs code, удалить все плагины кроме sftp , перезагрузить компуктер )
еще посмотрите чтобы в статус баре не было подключении типа ssh и прочих от других плагинов

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с аналогичной проблема на МакОС, на виндовс проверить не могу еще две недели без него
-Значек после установки не появляется

- При попытке вызвать файл sftp.json - всплывает внизу попап с просьбой казать путь к папке.

Решение просто, создал папку, открыл в VS , создаю файл sftp.json и записываю его в папку, нажимаю комбинацию cmd+ shift + P и вуаля, создается автоматически новый файл sftp.json. Если все поля заполнены верно то происходит подключение и появляется значек SFTP  слева, заходим в него и работаем.